# Create a shape an flip it in a webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, svg-animate

I am trying to use SVG but am open to other options.  Technically I have a shape which is a hexagon and I want an animation that flips it down on the x-axis.  Is SVG a good idea to use? I am open to other suggestions. I need it to work in IE 10+ and other modern browsers.  Is there another other ideas besides SVGs out there without using flash or another plugin?

Comment: The answer does not work.

Comment: Use flipY on a SVG matrix transform. See example at: http://svgdiscovery.com/flipY.htm

Comment: Add  a comment to the answer on your other question. Maybe it will get fixed. Or maybe someone else will answer it if you make it clearer what you want.